# trait not implemented error when using dependency from a local directory

Tags: rust

With this cargo.toml, code works fine:

```
[dependencies]
bellman = "0.6.0"
rand = "0.7"
pairing = {version = "0.16"}
sha2 = {version = "0.9.1"}
```

however, if I download 'pairing' and update the path in cargo.toml this way:

```
[dependencies]
bellman = "0.6.0"
rand = "0.7"
pairing = {version = "0.16", path = "../pairing"}
sha2 = {version = "0.9.1"}
```

I get and error stating that a certain trait is not implemented. What am I doing wrong?

The reason downloaded 'pairing' in the first place is that I want to modify some of the code there.

github link for the pairing crate: https://github.com/zkcrypto/pairing.git

Error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `E: ff::ScalarEngine` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:21:27
   |
21 | fn sha256t<E: Engine, CS: ConstraintSystem<E>>(
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ff::ScalarEngine` is not implemented for `E`
   |
help: consider further restricting this bound with `+ ff::ScalarEngine`
  --> src\main.rs:21:15
   |
21 | fn sha256t<E: Engine, CS: ConstraintSystem<E>>(
   |               ^^^^^^
   = note: required by `bellman::ConstraintSystem`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `E: ff::ScalarEngine` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:55:17
   |
55 | impl<E: Engine> Circuit<E> for MyCircuit {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ff::ScalarEngine` is not implemented for `E`
   |
help: consider further restricting this bound with `+ ff::ScalarEngine`
  --> src\main.rs:55:9
   |
55 | impl<E: Engine> Circuit<E> for MyCircuit {
   |         ^^^^^^

error[E0277]: the trait bound `E: ff::ScalarEngine` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:56:23
   |
56 |     fn synthesize<CS: ConstraintSystem<E>>(self, cs: &mut CS) -> Result<(), SynthesisError> {
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ff::ScalarEngine` is not implemented for `E`
   |
help: consider further restricting this bound with `+ ff::ScalarEngine`
  --> src\main.rs:55:9
   |
55 | impl<E: Engine> Circuit<E> for MyCircuit {
   |         ^^^^^^
   = note: required by `bellman::ConstraintSystem`

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `sha2`.
```

Comment: Please, specify where did you get this crate (e.g. githutb link & commit hash)

Comment: The complete error message might be helpful as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here that `bellman` depends on `pairing`. While you replacing a direct dependency (i.e. in your *Cargo.toml*), indirect dependency for `bellman` is still fetched from https://crates.io. You may "patch" it:

```
# this will replace all of the `pairing` crates to be fetched from crates-io
[patch.crates-io]
pairing = { path = '../pairing' }
```

A little bit more info [at cargo reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#the-patch-section). Besides, you may list all of the dependencies with `cargo tree` command, which might be helpful for finding such a crate.

Comment: so if I get this right, if I also download the 'bellman' crate, this should be resolved?
(in 'bellman' the dependency is also fetched from a local directory)

Comment: If you download `bellman` crate you also need to change a `pairing` dependency inside its _Cargo.toml_ (i.e. `pairing = "1.2.3"` -> `pairing = { path = ... }`), then it should work fine.