# Cargo can't import serde through git

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to import serde using the github repository on Cargo. For some reason Cargo simply does not work correctly when doing this way:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { git = "https://github.com/serde-rs/serde" , package = "serde"} 
serde_derive = { git = "https://github.com/serde-rs/serde" , package = "serde_derive"}
```

When importing from the git repo, I start getting this error from the structs to be deserialized:

```
the trait bound `__D: serde::de::Deserializer<'_>` is not satisfied
```

How do I actually import a project like serde that has subprojects from the git URL on Cargo?

Comment: Could you include the full error message? This sounds like the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Cargo would have failed to build the dependencies or the import (`use serde::Deserialize;`) would have errored first if there were issues with your usage of the git link. Chances are you either use that struct with a library that expects a different version of `serde` or `Deserialize` is not set up (or derived) correctly for your struct. This can be a common issue when deriving `Deserialize` for a struct containing references.

Comment: Now that I've written an answer, I know how to search for a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62772509/401059

Answer (score 4):

Normally, I would say: Please always provide the entire error message. But in this case, I can make an educated guess:

At minimum, you probably have some code like:

```rust
use serde_derive::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    a: i32,
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<Foo>("{\"a\":42}").unwrap());
}
```

The error message looks slightly different, but the cause is the same:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Foo: serde::de::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:10:45
     |
10   |     println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<Foo>("{\"a\":42}").unwrap());
     |                                             ^^^ the trait `serde::de::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `Foo`
```

I don't know what format you're actually deserializing from, so I'm using `serde_json` as an example. The problem is that `serde_json` itself (or any other format implementation) depends on `serde`, but doesn't know that you'd like to use `serde` from git. You can verify that this is happening on your end with `cargo tree --duplicates`:

```
serde v1.0.139
└── serde_json v1.0.82
    └── foo v0.1.0 (/tmp/foo)

serde v1.0.139 (https://github.com/serde-rs/serde#7cc6f7fb)
└── foo v0.1.0 (/tmp/foo)
```

Note how the `serde` dependency of `serde_json` doesn't have anything written in parenthesis behind it. That means it's coming from crates.io.

You can circumvent this by specifying that `serde` from crates.io be replaced by `serde` from git everywhere in your dependency tree:

```ini
[dependencies]
serde = "*"
serde_derive = "*"
serde_json = "1.0.82"

[patch.crates-io]
serde = { git = "https://github.com/serde-rs/serde", package = "serde" }
serde_derive = { git = "https://github.com/serde-rs/serde", package = "serde_derive" }
```

See also: [Dependency overriding](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html)